# Casting collection of objects from TempData (MVC C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, tempdata

I am trying to put my collection of objects into TempData like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult PandoraRemovalTotal2(List<Business.Models.Administration.CorrespondenceRecordViewModel> model, string hdnMem)
    {
        Business.Administration.Pandora Pandora = new Business.Administration.Pandora();
        model = Pandora.DeleteDocs(model);
        TempData["model"] = model.Where(m => m.DeleteRow == true);
        return RedirectToAction("PandoraDocsDeleted", new {memNum = hdnMem });
    }
```

**And pass it through redirect to action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PandoraDocsDeleted(string memNum)
{
    var model = (List<Business.Models.Administration.CorrespondenceRecordViewModel>)TempData["model"];
    ViewBag.MemNum = memNum;
    return View(model);
 }
```

But when I do this:

```
var model = (List<Business.Models.Administration.CorrespondenceRecordViewModel>)TempData["model"];
```

it is null. How do I cast this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
TempData["model"] = model.Where(m => m.DeleteRow == true);
```

Use

```
TempData["model"] = model.Where(m => m.DeleteRow == true).ToList();
```

Otherwise you are storing a definition for an IEnumerable<>, without any data.

Comment: Thanks your code worked. I was originally get a list of 0 items once I did the casting but that was a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,you answer helped me